# GORM refresh() method not getting latest data from database

Tags: grails, grails-orm

After saving a changed user name (using `flush:true`), the following expression evaluates to false:

```
User.get(u.getId()).name == u.refresh().name
```

The left hand side picks up the changed user name while the right hand side return the "old" value.

Ideas? Refreshing the "u" reference in the next HTTP request appears to work.

Answer (score 7):

Is this being done within a transaction? If your code is executing within a transaction then even using `flush: true` won't immediately persist changes to the database. Changes to domain objects made within a transaction are only flushed when the transaction ends.