# GORM Formula Not Being Calculated

Tags: grails, grails-orm, formula

I have the following Grails 2.4.3 Domain class

```
package invoicer

class Product {
    Float price
    Float taxRate
    Float tax

    static mapping = {
        tax formula: 'PRICE * TAX_RATE'
    }
}
```

I have created this Integration Test to verify the formula is being calculated properly

```
package invoicer;

import spock.lang.Specification

class ProductIntegrationSpec extends Specification {

    def "Test tax calculation"() {
        when:
        def p = new Product(price: 5.00, taxRate: 0.25)
        p.save(failOnError:true, flush: true)

        then:
        def newProduct = Product.get(1)
        newProduct.tax == (5.00 * 0.25)
    }
}
```

This test always fails thusly

```
grails> test-app -integration ProductIntegrationSpec
2014-10-16 11:29:15,225 [main] DEBUG hibernate.SQL  - 
    drop table product if exists
2014-10-16 11:29:15,230 [main] DEBUG hibernate.SQL  - 
    create table product (
        id bigint generated by default as identity,
        version bigint not null,
        price float not null,
        tax_rate float not null,
        primary key (id)
    )
======================================================================
                      Application: Invoicer 0.1                       
                      -------------------------                       
  Environment: TEST
  Database configuration: 
    Hibernate DDL mode: create
    URL: jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    Driver: org.h2.Driver
    User: sa
======================================================================
| Running 1 integration test... 1 of 1
2014-10-16 11:29:17,797 [main] DEBUG hibernate.SQL  - 
    /* insert invoicer.Product
        */ insert 
        into
            product
            (id, version, price, tax_rate) 
        values
            (null, ?, ?, ?)
2014-10-16 11:29:17,798 [main] TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [0]
2014-10-16 11:29:17,798 [main] TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [2] as [FLOAT] - [5.0]
2014-10-16 11:29:17,798 [main] TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [3] as [FLOAT] - [0.25]
| Failure:  Test tax calculation(invoicer.ProductIntegrationSpec)
|  Condition not satisfied:
newProduct.tax == (5.00 * 0.25)
|          |   |        |
|          |   false    1.2500
|          null
invoicer.Product : 1
    at invoicer.ProductIntegrationSpec.Test tax calculation(ProductIntegrationSpec.groovy:14)
| Completed 1 integration test, 1 failed in 0m 0s
| Tests FAILED  - view reports in /Users/XXX/git/invoicer/target/test-reports
```

I don't understand why this is failing, so I tried it out in the Grails Console with this code

```
import invoicer.*

def p = new Product(price: 5.00, taxRate: 0.25)
p.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)

def newProduct = Product.get(1)
assert newProduct.tax == (5.00 * 0.25)
```

It fails in the same way *the first time* run in the console

```
groovy>     import invoicer.* 
groovy>      
groovy>     def p = new Product(price: 5.00, taxRate: 0.25) 
groovy>     p.save(failOnError: true, flush: true) 
groovy>      
groovy>     def newProduct = Product.get(1) 
groovy>     assert newProduct.tax == (5.00 * 0.25) 

2014-10-16 11:34:31,140 [Thread-12] DEBUG hibernate.SQL  - 
    /* insert invoicer.Product
        */ insert 
        into
            product
            (id, version, price, tax_rate) 
        values
            (null, ?, ?, ?)

2014-10-16 11:34:31,162 [Thread-12] TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [0]

2014-10-16 11:34:31,163 [Thread-12] TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [2] as [FLOAT] - [5.0]

2014-10-16 11:34:31,164 [Thread-12] TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [3] as [FLOAT] - [0.25]

Exception thrown

Assertion failed: 

assert newProduct.tax == (5.00 * 0.25)
       |          |   |        |
       |          |   false    1.2500
       |          null
       invoicer.Product : 1

    at ConsoleScript0.run(ConsoleScript0:7)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
```

When run again in the same console session though, it works just fine!

```
groovy>     import invoicer.* 
groovy>      
groovy>     def p = new Product(price: 5.00, taxRate: 0.25) 
groovy>     p.save(failOnError: true, flush: true) 
groovy>      
groovy>     def newProduct = Product.get(1) 
groovy>     assert newProduct.tax == (5.00 * 0.25) 

2014-10-16 11:36:20,612 [Thread-13] DEBUG hibernate.SQL  - 
    /* insert invoicer.Product
        */ insert 
        into
            product
            (id, version, price, tax_rate) 
        values
            (null, ?, ?, ?)

2014-10-16 11:36:20,613 [Thread-13] TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [0]

2014-10-16 11:36:20,613 [Thread-13] TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [2] as [FLOAT] - [5.0]

2014-10-16 11:36:20,614 [Thread-13] TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [3] as [FLOAT] - [0.25]

2014-10-16 11:36:20,620 [Thread-13] DEBUG hibernate.SQL  - 
    select
        product0_.id as id1_7_0_,
        product0_.version as version2_7_0_,
        product0_.price as price3_7_0_,
        product0_.tax_rate as tax_rate4_7_0_,
        product0_.PRICE * product0_.TAX_RATE as formula0_0_ 
    from
        product product0_ 
    where
        product0_.id=?

2014-10-16 11:36:20,621 [Thread-13] TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
```

Note that there is a select statement logged for the second run where the tax is calculated, but none for the first run!  I'm stumped as to why the console behavior fails the first time and why it runs properly the second time.  I suppose the answer to that question would explain why the integration test always fails.  Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: just some unrelated advice: don't ever use float for monetary calculations.  sooner than later you will hunt down penny errors or worse.  use `BugDecimal`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @cfrick.  Yes, Float is bad, but this problem had me stumped for so long, I regressed to using the example in the GORM docs.

Answer (score 3):

I finally figured it out.  Calling

```
save(flush: true)
```

is not sufficient.  The key is to re-query the database, because that is when the where-clause generates the formula.  After saving the domain object, one must call

```
refresh()
```

on it.  That re-queries the database and populates the formula-based field.

Comment: Note: this won't work in an integration test. The `@Rollback` annotation makes each feature test run in a transaction, and [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4686944/2521769), `flush: true` and `refresh()` don't have any effect until after the transaction has ended.